# Blender , an angle between faces

Tags: python

I have such an example:
On an object
the obtuse angle between 2 faces is 150 deg (but I know it, blender shows 30), in another place the acute angle between 2  different faces is 30 deg.
In both cases, Blender shows me 30 deg. How could I find the difference with Python help

Comment: The value shown is `face1.normal.angle(face2.normal)`

Comment: yes, i used that , but it shows me 30 deg in both cases

Comment: actually it shows me 30 when i use degrees(face1.normal.angle(face2.normal))  , face1.normal.angle(face2.normal) gives me values:0,1,or 2

Comment: is there anyone who could help me somehow?